# How to add parameter to link.asmx

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" 
        xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" 
        xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
    "<soap:Body>"
    "<FillFloorsNew xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
    "<BlockId>String</BlockId>"
    "</FillFloorsNew>"
    "</soap:Body>"
    "</soap:Envelope>
```

I want to pass block id

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <FillFloorsNew xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <BlockId>string</BlockId>
    </FillFloorsNew>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: I want to pass block id in this link http://abc/webserviceUser.asmx?op=FillFloorsNew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add parameter like this

```
 NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" 
        xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" 
        xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
    "<soap:Body>"
    "<FillFloorsNew xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
    "<BlockId>String</BlockId>"
    "</FillFloorsNew>"
    "</soap:Body>"
    "</soap:Envelope>",BlockId];
```